# What should I use on my Android application to view a calendar?

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, simpledateformat

I have created an Android application and I am want to display calendar on the application so that user can select some date. I tried accomplishing it using CalendarView, but ended up with nothing. In calendarView, setMinDate sets the default calendar view to 2100 and also there is some problem with the dates after 2038, I guess.

What do I need to do in order to view a calendar on my android application with past days disabled.(But not with calendarview, fed up and tried everything on it!)

Comment: Do you want the user to select more than one date at a time ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, that's not my requirement. My requirement is that user needs to enter a date apart from the past days.

Comment: Did you try datepicker in dialog

Comment: No, I didn't. I just used CalendarView.

Comment: I used CalendarView I got stuck and now I am here searching other ways!

Comment: Do you have any component on click of which you want  your user to select date

Comment: Yes, I have it. Actually what I am trying to do is store some other stuff with the date selected onto mysql database.

Comment: Check the below code it will open datepicker for you and you ll be able to select date also set the min date below which all dates will be disabled and user will not be able to select that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     @SuppressLint({"NewApi"})
        public void showDatePicker() {
           DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    //               Log.e("cal", "year= "+ year + " month= "+ dayOfMonth+ " day= "+ dayOfMonth);
                   String monthh = (1 + monthOfYear) + "";
                   if (monthh.length() != 2) {
                       monthh = "0" + monthh;
                   }
                   String dayy = (dayOfMonth) + "";
                   if (dayy.length() != 2) {
                       dayy = "0" + dayy;
                   }

                   String str = year
                           + "-" + monthh
                           + "-" + dayy;                  
    //                Log.e("Date dialog", str);
                   selected_date=str;   

               }
           },
 Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),       Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
          //  datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate();// here you can set your min date below which the user cannot select any date.
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
```

Let me know if it solves your problem else we ll go for some other approach.

Comment: Sure I will try it and get back to you if its resolved!

Comment: Its working fine! But what if I do not want a dialog box and I need a UI element like a calendar view. Sorry, if I am illogical because I am a newbie in Android programming.

Comment: You can try with datepicked in xml

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I will get it resolved now! Got the logic behind it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Hey check this code.

```
 long date = selected.getTimeInMillis();
 long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

 if (date1 < date) 
 {
   closePopup();
 } 
 else
   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Past date reminder can not be set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate!                  Calendar selected = Calendar.getInstance();  //selected has current date right?

Comment: @AvinashJaiswal yes..I had done this in my project.If you found useful you can vote for it.

Comment: Thanks mate! I will get it resolved combining your logic with datepicker. Thanks once again!